# npm WARN config only Use `--omit=dev`

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, package.json

I have a simple node.js project. I dockerized it by Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=prod
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When I run `docker build -t my-service:1.0 .`, I get warning:

```
 > [4/5] RUN npm install --only=prod:
#9 1.042 npm WARN config only Use `--omit=dev` to omit dev dependencies from the install.
```

Does it mean Docker suggest me to use `--omit=dev` instead of `--only=prod:` to not install dev dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

It's a weird message to say "Don't use A, use B instead." Changing from the one to the other is what I did to get rid of the warnings on my four containers.

It appears that npm-ci no longer includes an "only" option, however the `--omit=dev` seems to do the same thing:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci#omit

I think the `--only=prod` may date back to node 12-14ish, I couldn't find any official references to date it, just that the syntax was used in blog posts dating around 2020 at the latest.